# How to read all the data from socket using tokio

Tags: rust, tcp, network-programming, rust-tokio, picamera

I am trying to read data from the socket using tokio. The data is the bytes sent by Picamera, which I read from my code and write to a file. When I run the file it seems like there are some fragments lost in the middle. The code for the above is:

```
let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8080").await?;
    println!("Server started listening");
    loop {
        let (mut socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut buf = [0; 1024];
            let f = File::create("./test.h264").expect("Unable to create file");
            let mut f = BufWriter::new(f);
            // In a loop, read data from the socket and write the data back.
            loop {
                let n = match socket.read(&mut buf).await {
                    // socket closed
                    Ok(n) if n == 0 => return,
                    Ok(n) => {
                        f.write_all(&buf[0..n]).expect("Write failed");
                        n
                    },
                    Err(e) => {
                        eprintln!("failed to read from socket; err = {:?}", e);
                        return;
                    }
                };

                // Write the data back
                // if let Err(e) = socket.write_all(&buf[0..n]).await {
                //     eprintln!("failed to write to socket; err = {:?}", e);
                //     return;
                // }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am unable to figure out what is happening. I think I have specified the bugger of size 1024, and when it reads 1024 while writing to the file, some packets are lost before it starts reading again. I may be wrong. I want to maintain a constant video stream captured from my pi. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me. However it looks like you're using the standard `File` and `BufWriter`, you should use those from tokio instead (if you're already using the tokio versions, then you're missing an `await` after `f.write_all(&buf[0..n])`)

Comment: I'm not completely sure but, could you try like this (https://gist.github.com/zeppi/99c09309f54095d7a4bf07b9d9ff15d1)